# X Y Co-ordinates of WebElement on Mobile Screen using Selenium's Point and Dimension class is wrong

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

When I find out x, y co-ordinates of WebElement on Mobile Screens using Point and Dimension Classes of Selenium webdriver. It gives co-ordinates value different.

For Example: Below is XPath of WebElement and Code snippet

```
WebElement plusYouXp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“.//*[@id='p_p_id_QuoteHomeBTemplate_WAR_PeDevportlet_']/div/div/div[2]/form/ul/li[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/h1/span"));

System.out.println("plusUxpath: "+plusYouXp.getText()); 

Point p = plusYouXp.getLocation();
Dimension size = plusYouXp.getSize();
int xAxis = p.x + (size.width/2);
int yAxis = p.y + (size.height/2);
System.out.println(xAxis+" -- “+yAxis);

changeContextToNativeAppView();
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.tap(1, xAxis, yAxis, 1);
```

Here, it doesn't tap on correct x,y values As X & Y values after calculation of Java Code here is 180 & 495

On the other hand, when I find out co ordinates using Pointer location from Developer Options

As shown below:

[image]

In Figure 2(As shown above): It gives correct co-ordinates, as shown below in highlighted section

[image]

This co-ordinates worked for this command

```
driver.tap(1,554,1067,200);
```

I want to know, How can I find out exact co-ordinates using Java code for Appium or Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement plusYouXp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“.//*[@id='p_p_id_QuoteHomeBTemplate_WAR_PeDevportlet_']/div/div/div[2]/form/ul/li[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/h1/span"));

center_x=plusYouXp.getSize().getHeight()/2;
center_y=plusYouXp.getSize().getWidth()/2;
System.out.println(center_x+" "+center_y);
```

Comment: Hi Abhinav,Thanks for your response but it is not working. It is giving x,y value as 19 & 34. But actual value should be 554,1067 as per screenshot.

Comment: The value will be in reference to element. You can tap as pe this value.